# Does CatBoost support .NET deployment?

Tags: .net, catboost

Does CatBoost support .NET deployments? The Docs link has a section for .NET deployments, which links to an empty tutorial folder repository on the CatBoost repository.

The docs:
https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/apply-dotnet.html

The repository folder:
https://github.com/catboost/tutorials/tree/master/apply_model/dotnet

Would really love some help with this if this functionality exists, it would make using CatBoost much easier for our application.

Comment: Seems like somebody else had the same problem and CatBoost is not really have any info about .NET part. See here:https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/1434